# Show product image in WooCommerce email template

Tags: php, wordpress, email, templates, woocommerce

I am using the following code in my email template.
`<?php echo wc_get_email_order_items($order, array( 'show_sku' => $sent_to_admin, 'show_image' => true, 'image_size' => array(75, 75), 'plain_text' => $plain_text, 'sent_to_admin' => $sent_to_admin, )); ?>`
But using this code I am getting a product thumbnail, I want to get a featured image or full image. Plz help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
wc_get_email_order_items($order, array( 'show_sku' => $sent_to_admin, 'show_image' => true, 'image_size' => 'full', 'plain_text' => $plain_text, 'sent_to_admin' => $sent_to_admin, ));
```

The parameter `image_size` - Accepts any registered image size name, or an array of width and height values in pixels (in that order). Default 'thumbnail' ('woocommerce_thumbnail', 'full', 'woocommerce_single', 'woocommerce_gallery_thumbnail')

Comment: Fantastic brother

Comment: Now the problem is how to control the size. I mean getting the correct image but it's too big.